# In Install4j, How to set a relative path in varfile?

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j project that I'm running from both GUI and command line.
As you might know it is possible to pass installer parameters in varfile.
I would like to know if there is a simple way to give a relative path in the varfile in the form:
my.variable=${installer:installerDir}\a.txt

I can see a workaround where I can ask the user to specify the file name only and I will put the directory path in the code. but I would still like to know if this is possible.

Thanks.
Ika.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use installer variables in the variable file. That file is read at startup before any other installer variables are defined, so you would not have a chance to set up the "installerDir" variable first.

The only option I see here is to use your own token, say

my.variable=@installerDir@\a.txt

and use a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node to replace that token with a particular directory. Here's some which checks all defined variables:

```java
    String installerDir = null;
    InstallerContext context = null;
    for (Object o : context.getVariableNames()) {
        String variableName = (String)o;
        Object variableValue = context.getVariable(variableName);
        if (variableValue instanceof String) {
            String replacedValue = ((String)variableValue).replaceAll("@installerDir@", installerDir);
            if (!replacedValue.equals(variableValue)) {
                context.setVariable(variableName, replacedValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up solving this by generating the varfile.